# how to get datas of same arrays from jsonObject to a list with android

Tags: android, json, expandable

I made a web page to make json by php, now I want to get data from json by android but I want to put arrays with same id to a list and finally I put it to hashmap for every object to make expandableListview, I mean:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [author] => x
            [book] => y
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [author] => w
        [book] => a
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [author] => x
        [book] => y2
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [author] => x
        [book] => y3
    )

)
```

and the json result is :

```
{"authors":[{"id":"1","author":"x","book":"y"},`{"id":"2","author":"w","book":"a"},{"id":"1","author":"x","book":"y2"},{"id":"1","author":"x","book":"y3"}]}`
```

and my code in android to get data from json:

```
public static HashMap<String,List<String>> toPerson(String json){

    try {
        JSONObject jsonPerson = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray jsonDataAuthor = jsonPerson.getJSONArray("authors");
        HashMap<String ,List<String>> author=new HashMap<String ,List<String>>();

        for(int i=0; i<jsonDataAuthor.length(); i++){
            List<String> bookOfAuthor=new ArrayList<String>();
            JSONObject jsonPn = jsonDataAuthor.getJSONObject(i);
            String authorName = jsonPn.getString("author");
            String bookName = jsonPn.getString("book");
            bookOfAuthor.add(bookName);
            author.put(authorName,bookOfAuthor);
        }
        return author;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

but I get expandable list view with there parents and every parent has only one child, but here with a same id I want a expandable list view with two parents that one of them has 3 children but I don't know how, I want below result:

x

- y
- y2
- y3

w

- a

I'd appreciate to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new list in each iteration:

```
List<String> bookOfAuthor=new ArrayList<String>();
```

Move this outside the for loop. If your `HashMap` contains `ArrayList` for given id, bring it and put your `bookName` to the list. Otherwise you will keep creating a new `ArrayList` in each iteration and you won't have more than 1 item.

Something like that. I might have syntax errors, I just put this together to give you an idea:

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonPerson = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONArray jsonDataAuthor = jsonPerson.getJSONArray("authors");
    HashMap<String ,List<String>> author=new HashMap<String ,List<String>>();
    List<String> bookOfAuthor;

    for(int i=0; i<jsonDataAuthor.length(); i++){

        JSONObject jsonPn = jsonDataAuthor.getJSONObject(i);
        String authorName = jsonPn.getString("author");
        String bookName = jsonPn.getString("book");

        if (author.contains(authorName)){
            bookOfAuthor = author.get(authorName);
        } else {
            bookOfAuthor = new ArrayList<>();     
        }

        bookOfAuthor.add(bookName);
        author.put(authorName,bookOfAuthor);
    }
    return author;
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
```

Comment: when i do it, again i have there parents that all of them has one and same children, i need to send only one Arraylist for all of same id

Comment: If you copied and pasted my code, it wouldn't work. As I said, it was just to give you an idea. Now I updated my code, fixed couple bugs. Stil it might be buggy. The idea is to use same ArrayList for given id.